# How to nest a view controller in Storyboard

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

Is there a substitute for fragments in Android for IOS apps? For example, I want to create a view with a sidebar. So, I have a container which holds 2 other views. For now, I am doing everything programmatically. Like creating 3 view controller: for the container, sidebar and home screen. I am adding later 2 using addSubView method but I would like to nest view controller in storyboard instead of adding viewcontrollers programmatically. I can nest view controller programmatically but want to do same using drop and drag interface.

I am using the following code to add subviews:

```
        let homeController = HomeController()
        homeController.delegate = self
        centreController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeController)

        view.addSubview(centreController!.view)
        addChild(centreController!)
        centreController?.didMove(toParent: self)
```

So, is there a way to get the same effect using storyboard? I am new to IOS so might be missing some common feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing in UIKit would probably be a Container View Controller:

From Android Developer Docs (fragment):

> **You can think of a fragment as a modular section of an activity, which has its own lifecycle, receives its own input events, and which you can add or remove while the activity is running (sort of like a "sub activity" that you can reuse in different activities).**

From IOS Developer Docs (Container View Controller):

> **Container view controllers promote better encapsulation by separating out your content from how you display that content onscreen. Unlike a content view controller that displays your app’s data, a container view controller displays other view controllers, arranging them onscreen and handling navigation between them.**

[image: Container View Controller]

### Step 1

Drag the `UIContainerView` from the component selection library as you would a normal view. Xcode will create a new ViewController for it.

[image]

### Step 2

Add normal view constraints to the Container View, the same as any view component.

### Step 3

Use the Container View Controller as an independent container.

[image]

I made a demo project for you: https://github.com/atapp/ContainerDEMO

Comment: Thanks a lot for help. This is exactly what I am looking for.